# What happens if I called Dispose() before using statement end?

Tags: c#, using-statement

I have this code, I am concerned that it is "not safe"
I used Dispose() before the using statement end, for me it is slightly illogical, but it works just fine. So, is it safe?

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(SfilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HighscoresViewModel));
        HVM = deserializer.Deserialize(stream) as HighscoresViewModel;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) 
    {
        stream.Dispose();
        (new FileInfo(SfilePath)).Delete();
        HVM = new HighscoresViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will try to dispose the object twice

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: that is incorrect. See hwd's answer.

Comment: @siride - the `stream` _will_ be disposed twice. The only error in Jeroens comment is the word 'try'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I looked at the decompiled code for Stream and FileStream and there are checks to prevent duplicate disposal. That is, the second call does nothing, which matches hvd's answer.

Comment: Indeed, the second Dispose() does nothing, as per the specs.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: so...what's the disagreement here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for [`IDisposable.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) states:

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when resources are already disposed.

Assuming `IDisposable` is implemented correctly, this use is safe. `Dispose` will be called a second time, and will do nothing that second time.

Answer (score 1):

Well as said by @hvd that this use is safe; but it's not recommended cause if you implement Microsoft `Fxcop` on your code sample it will throw an Fxcop warning/error `CA2202: Do not dispose objects multiple times`

[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx)

Which says

> A method implementation contains code paths that could cause multiple
>   calls to IDisposable.Dispose or a Dispose equivalent, such as a
>   Close() method on some types, on the same object.